# Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DesignTimeProviderServicesAttribute'

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I use Visual Studio for Mac, created a .net core web api project.
The csproj file is like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.9-dmr" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.9-dmr" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.1" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When I execute "dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold" to scaffold from MySQL with the following command:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "server=[server];port=3306;user=[user];password=[password];database=[dbname]" MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -o Models -c [contextname] -f -v
```

The command returned error like this:

```
Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DesignTimeProviderServicesAttribute' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
```

I checked the package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. It is true that no Infrastructure namespace in that package. But Searched online, I find others can successfully scaffold with such settings.
Is there anything I did wrong?
How can I scaffold correctly?

Thank you all.

Comment: Try to add include individual packages instead of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`

Comment: What?
 https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/tree/dev/src/EFCore/Infrastructure

Comment: This is issue in MySQL provider package. The `DesignTimeProviderServicesAttribute` used to live in Infrastructure namespace in 1.x release. It was moved to Design namespace in 2.0 version. Since it is major version change, there can be various breaking changes. Though MySQL package target both EF Core version (1.1.4 & 2.0.0) at the same time. It is highly unlikely to work correctly in all scenarios

Comment: So, @Smit do you have any work around about this?

Comment: One work-around would be target 1.1.4 version to scaffold the database and then switch to 2.0.0 version. If you can find a way to do some type forwarding so that you can re-map type to new namespace then it could work but I am not sure how to do it on netcoreapps.

Answer (score 7):

you should add `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` package from NuGet packages, this worked for me. hope, this works for you too.

Comment: +1 Worked also for me, thanks.
The problem occurred on my side because I installed `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design` after `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` and did not notice that the latter was downgraded from 3.1 to 1.6 during installing the first package.